# How to use "promise to do something" without ambiguity?

Tags: word-choice

I want to write "he promises to do something after event x". My concern is that the phrase "after event x" could be referring to either a) the time when he makes the promise or b) the time when the promised thing is done. How do I make sure the reader understands it is b) rather than a)?

Comment: Don't use an infinitive, then. Infinitives are timeless. Use a tensed clause: _He promises that he will do something after the event_. That puts the promise in the present, before the event, and the activity in the future, after it.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it to make it more explicit:

- *He promises to do the thing after the event x is over.*

Comment: Or "after X happens" or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's very ambiguous. You wouldn't normally use the present tense to describe something happening at a specific time (although this style is sometimes used when reporting a sequence of actions, e.g. "he shoots, he scores!").

And while the sentence is literally ambiguous, usually the time frame refers to the closest verb for which it makes sense. If you wanted to express the time when the promise is made, you'd say

> After the event is over, he promises to do something.

Relocating the prepositional phrase closer to "promise" makes it refer to that action.